# Why is there a 1-D array constructed in case of unbounded knapsack and 2-D array constructed in case of 0/1 knapsack?

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I saw that a 1-D array is constructed in case of unbounded knapsack and a 2-D array is constructed in case of 0/1 knapsack? Why does this happen? This question is asked in reference to dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Progrmamming works by maintaining "states", ofcourse you'd want to represent a state using minimal variables.

Now, These two problems differ in that fact that you can pick single item as many times as you want in Unbounded knapsack problem, However, In 0-1 knapsack problem, you can pick a item only once. This means, I would want to include whether i already picked a item from list in 0-1 Knapsack problem but there's no need to do so in 0-1 knapsack problem. This is exactly the reason for 2nd dimension in 0-1 Knapsack problem.

See, DP of 0-1 Knapsack : `dp[i][w] =  max(val[i] + dp[i-1][w-wt[i]],  K[i-1][w]);` . This represent either pick item `i` and get best solution for items  `i-1` with weight `w - wt[i]` , which makes sure we don't pick item i more than once.

See DP of Unbounded Knapsack: `dp[w] = max(dp[w], dp[w - wt[i] ] + val[i] )` . There's no need to remember whether we have picked `ith` item before, we could just reuse it, if it gives us maximum value.

Comment: I think this statement is wrong : ``` This means, I would want to include whether i already picked a item from list in 0-1 Knapsack problem but there's no need to do so in 0-1 knapsack problem. .. I think you mean to say :  ```  but there's no need to do so in unbounded knapsack problem. ```

Comment: Still not clear .. could you please elaborate :   This means, I would want to include whether i already picked a item from list in 0-1 Knapsack problem but there's no need to do so in 0-1 knapsack problem. This is exactly the reason for 2nd dimension in 0-1 Knapsack problem.